# Android: Google plus sign-in, error = 4

Tags: android, google-plus

downloaded Google plus sign-in example application from here:
https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android

But when I click on GooglePlus button, I received error all the time:

ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = 4

Why it occurs ?

On this page there is Troubleshooting section :

> If you are seeing ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = 4 when trying to
>   connect, ensure that the consent screen is configured and saved.

What that means ? What should I do ?

Comment: Oh, now I now what is content screen.

Found answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22505607/602011

Answer (score 1):

**I know this is old question but this may help other to solve problem ,

if you are getting code 4 error then**

Follow these stem in android developme [Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console)

1. Open the Credentials page.
2. Click Add credentials > OAuth 2.0 client ID.

[image]

3. Select Android.
   and fill the fingerprint and package name .

[image]

4. Click Create.

Then there will be successful sing in from google.

Please msg me if any problem occurs. Hope this may solve your problem. !!!

Comment: Still it ain't working, gives error : 4, the plugin seems buggy

Answer (score 0):

You have not configured the *consent screen* for project under `API/Auths` section in Google Developer Console.