# "An internal error occurred" while login Google+ in signed apk

Tags: android, api, google-plus

I am stuck with this issue.
When i run the apk from bin then works properly.
But when i create signed apk using keystore then a toast of "An internal error occurred" .
Please help me out.
Suggestion appreciated.

Thanks 
Kind regards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762904/an-internal-error-occurred-with-integration-of-google-plus-login

Comment: Please post your error here..

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I followed correctly all steps defined here at https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android

And still there error occured for me, the solution was to actually set an email address in the Consent Screen in the Developer Console. As soon as I set my email address in that form, it started working.

You can find the Consent Screen under **API and auths**. Just fill required fields and submit.

[image]

I hope this helps you.