# Google+ Share Error Code 8

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

when implementing Google+ share i do the following in `onCreate`:

```
mGoogleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addApi(Drive.API)
    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .build();
```

i conntect to Google after `onClick` on a button:

```
mGoogleClient.connect();
```

then callback is called:

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("GoogleClient","connection failed!");
    Log.e("result",""+ result.getErrorCode());
    if (result.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            mGoogleClient.connect();
        }
    }
    // Speichern Sie das Ergebnis und beheben Sie den Verbindungsfehler bei einem Klick des Nutzers.
    mGoogleConnectionResult = result;

}
```

And i get Error Code `8`, `12-28 22:39:56.286: E/result(15533): ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}`.

I added my APK to Google and got a valid release key. I know that because the first time i tried to share it works like a charm and i was able to share on my `Google+ page`. If i tried it again nothing happens, not even the `Choose Google-account` Dialog appears. If i uninstall my app and reinstall it and then try again, `Choose Google-account` Dialog appears when i choose my `Google Account` as i did the first time i get Error Code `8` -----> `12-28 22:39:56.286: E/result(15533): ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}`.

I got the latest Android SDK and the latest `Google Play Services`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ccording to https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/, you do not need to call `connect()``. You just need to launch an Intent.

Comment: @joao2fast4u that is so true. It fixed the Problem and now it works like a charm everytime. You can post it as an answere i will mark as accepted. But anyway, it is just luck that `googe+ share` don't Need to be connected. It would be interesting why this is not working when trying to connect.. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Google Developers website](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/), you do not need to call `connect()` to share with `Google Plus`. You just need to launch a Share `Intent`.

**Edit**: About your last comment, the possible cause to your issue is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762904/an-internal-error-occurred-with-integration-of-google-plus-login).