# Android with Google Plus Sign-in Error

Tags: android, google-plus

After searching for an answer and trying everything possible I have ran out of options but to ask it myself.

After following [Android with Google+ Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in%20Android%20Google+%20Signin) tutorial I ran into the most annoying and least descriptive error ever, the "An internal error occurred" on device. Nothing in the logs. The thing is, that after clicking the Sign-in button on virtual device I DO get prompted with permission requests, but running the same application on an actual device keeps throwing the error.

I did fill in the consent page, check the package names, create a new key and check package names and keys again and so on, nothing seems to work.

If anyone has had the same experience (working on AVD but not on actual device) please do throw anything at me, no matter how silly it might be.

Cheers!

P.S. Forgot the crucial part! If "addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)" is removed the application calls the onConnected method. So I guess I need an alternative for the same row that would keep the scope I need.

Comment: This is often due to the signing key of the application not having been registered on the GoogleDevelopers Console. Can you confirm that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762904/an-internal-error-occurred-with-integration-of-google-plus-login for more details

Comment: If you are referring to creating new client ID with SHA1 based on keytool on the console then yes. If it was the other way around the application would fail on AVD too, right? (Yes as in I can confirm I did that)

Comment: Extended the original question with more info.

Comment: When you say you've removed `addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)` does that mean you've got no scope at all? In which case I don't think you'd find it's really connected.

Comment: Do you have a real android device to test on? That might give you better results. Also, you'll need to make sure your emulator has the correct image. Namely the Google API image (see here for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000548/google-play-services-in-emulator-implementing-google-plus-login-button-etc)

Comment: Didn't know that the connection didn't exist at all without the scope. My bad then.

Comment: As stated in the question the problem IS real device. The application works within AVD but not on real device.

Comment: Please go to https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#frequently_asked_questions and use the FAQ example to enable VERBOSE logging on the object. It might provide major insight

Comment: Already have verbose enabled in Android Studio.