# Getting An internal error occured in google + login integration

Tags: android, google-plus

I integrating G+ and fb in my android app. But G+ shows internal err.. I dont know to solve it.

I tried the link ["An internal error occurred" with integration of Google Plus Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762904/an-internal-error-occurred-with-integration-of-google-plus-login)

but not successfull, kindly help to solve it. 
Thank you

Comment: Hey Can you give me your code ? because I also want to add this feature in my app. can you mail me ?

Comment: I used this link https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android#install-sdk