# Google+ Android: sign in failed

Tags: android, oauth, google-plus, google-oauth

I have created my app in google api console, then I activated Google+ API and created client id(oAuth). But after this my android app worked incorrectly and I have deleted it from google api console, deleted client id(oAuth) and recreated. So I create new project and new client Id(oAuth) in new project. But when I try to login in google+ in my app I see next error: "Sign in failed. Error signing in the specified account. Please choose a different account". When I choose different account it's same. If I disable Google+ API error also same! What is it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762904/an-internal-error-occurred-with-integration-of-google-plus-login Solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the release mode or debug mode?This sounds like there is a mismatch of keys or package name. According to [google](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) when you switch from debug mode to release mode you have also to create a new OAuth 2.0 client ID for your production app.
if you have released your app on google play you can use this command:

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore c:\you_key_here.key
```

to confirm if the key signed with your application on the store is the same as the one you used do define your Client ID for Android application on google developer console